# Automatic A/C recirculation problem

Tags: electrical, toyota, ac

I have a Toyota 2014 4-Runner limited and I have a problem where the recirculation button will automatically turn off. It works fine when it's on, but is there a way to turn off the auto turn off?

Comment: After how long does it turn off? It might be in a mode that deliberately turns it off after a set time...

Comment: This is not a defect. This is the way it works on most cars! Not sure about the reason behind it.

Comment: Look at this question for example: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15196/ford-escape-2014-is-there-a-practical-reason-why-climate-recirculation-is-on-a/15213#15213

Comment: When you say it turns off, at what point does it turn off? Randomly? Or do you mean when you shut off the car and then turn it back on?

Comment: @Paulster2  sorry its taken so long to respond. It usually shuts off after turning the car off, but on long trips it will shut off on its own.

Comment: It's normal behavior for the recirc to shut off when shutting the car off (on most cars). That it's shutting off on long trips is new to me. I don't know if Toyota has a "feature" like this. Would be nice to figure it out, I'm sure.

Comment: This is a bug rather than a feature.  My friend has the same cabin his 2013 Tacoma and the recirc does not work this way.  This is a warranty issue IMO.